# concise Angular form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using Angular 1.4.7 and want to show field validation errors when a form is submitted (rather than when the content of a field changes). My current approach looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
                .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.addUser = function (userDetails) {
                        if (myForm.$valid) {
                            // send form data to server, or whatever....
                        } else {
                            $scope.showValidation = true;
                        }
                    };

                    $scope.getError = function (error) {
                        if (angular.isDefined(error)) {
                            if (error.required) {
                                return "Please enter a value";
                            } else if (error.email) {
                                return "Please enter a valid email address";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    </script>
    <style>
        form.validate .ng-invalid-required.ng-dirty {
            background-color: lightpink;
        }

        form.validate .ng-invalid-email.ng-dirty {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }

        div.error {
            color: red; font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="todoPanel" class="panel" ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="addUser(newUser)"
          ng-class="showValidation ? 'validate' : ''">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input name="userEmail" type="email" class="form-control"
                       required ng-model="newUser.email">
                <div class="error" ng-show="showValidation">
                    {{getError(myForm.userEmail.$error)}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">OK</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the `$scope.showValidation` is used to ensure that validation messages are not displayed until the form is submitted. `$scope.getError` is used to reduce the amount of markup needed to figure out which message to display (though in this example the form only has one field).

I feel like there must be a better way, in code required to display the appropriate error message becomes pretty verbose when a form has lots of fields, and there are several different ways in which a field can be invalid. Is there a way to simplify the code above or make it more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly better approach would be the usage of `ng-messages`.

[From the docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
</div>
```

Another approach is to fully control your `form` through JavaScript. There is a nice library called [formly](http://angular-formly.com/) which reduces all that boilerplate code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `$submitted` to check, if the form has already been sent. `$touched` may be used to check, whether the form element has already been modified.

As its IMO the best way to provide feedback, whether as form element is valid or not, as soon as possible, i use checks like this to ensure, that the error message is shown if the element is invalid and already had focus (i.e. was filled wrong) or the form was submitted. This looks like this (which may be more sophisticated if you want to print custom error messages like 'too short', etc.)

```
function isInvalid(form, elem) {
    return (elem.$touched || form.$submitted) && elem.$error;
}
```